# How to put zend radio in an extended table

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, smarty, zend-form-element, zend-decorators

I'm trying to build a form in the Zend Frameword in which there has to be a table like this:

[image: example]

So, it's a radiobutton followed by some descriptions about a subscription of some sorts. I have googled myself senseless, but can't make this happen. I have tried several form-decorators, but it seems that the radiobuttons stick together, and you can only wrap a whole group of radiobuttons in an html-tag...

The form will be rendered by a Smarty template, but I can't get the individual radio-buttons in the template. Maybe somebody has some experience with this.

Does anybody have an idea or a link to get me going with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is  suited for View Script Decorator .

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript